# Where to download your_client_secret_File.json file

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am using YouTube API but first, I need the credential file which is your_client_secret_File.json. By following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query in python section. I could not find the (Download Json) as they said.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Where to download this JSON file is explicitly stated in the instructions.

1. Go to your [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis) where you'll login using your Gmail account.
2. Head to Credentials to create an OAuth Client ID of type Other.
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query

**Credentials page looks like this**:
[image]

**Select OAuth client ID and choose Other**:

[image]

**After creating it, it'll appear on your list of credentials**:

[image]

**You can DOWNLOAD it by clicking the 'DOWN' arrow on the farthest right of the page**:

[image]