# Youtube Data API: Python Quickstart: Authorisation URL is 'Not Verified by Google'

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz3Gz.png)

The authorization URL as an output of the example python program from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true
leads me to a webpage. It says: 'This App is not Verified by Google'. Help needed.

Comment: The given image is a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Hey Mappy and welcome. I just tried the link on Firefox and it works just fine. Maybe try another browser. You can also try and clear your current browsers cache. Try and provide a bit more information next time, like OS you're using, browser, what you have tried to solve the problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Mappy, you need to create credentials in [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), you get a [token as client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200589/where-to-download-your-client-secret-file-json-file) there for pre-production tasks and limited consent screen too. When you'll ready, your app needs to be verified by Google ([Auth Consent Screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) and [OAuth Scopes for Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)).

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(

    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A minimum test in terminal works to me.

```sh
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=Me%20dicen%20Dai&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Oauth Consent Screen configuration of google add the scope and it will show you an Orange triangle if verification is needed for your selected scope.

The cause of this error is because many of Google scopes need app verification before u can use it with external users.

Also, this url will tell you whether the requested scope might fall into the Sensitive or Restricted category

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

Comment: But when I submit it for verification, it asks for mandatory application homepage link, and application privacy policy link. But I have neither. Please help.

Comment: :) you would have to provide this to move forward. You could do it asynchronously and get you development sorted while the verification is in process