# The Option to select 'Other' for a client ID in the OAuth in the Google APIs is not available

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am attempting to utilize the YouTube API in order to pull a list of my subscribers from the site. I had to get Credentials and create an API client. In researching this step, I was advised to choose 'Other' as the client ID option, but currently there is no option for other. You can see the options in this picture:

[image: Picture of Google APIs options for creating client ID for OAuth]

This question provides some context for mine:
[Where to download your_client_secret_File.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200589/where-to-download-your-client-secret-file-json-file/62528151?noredirect=1#comment110579023_62528151)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google keeps changing the naming of it If your interested this is the progression of their naming.

- other
- native
- desk top app

either way pick desktop app for an app that will be running standalone on a machine some where and not running via a website or mobile device.